# How to search by city in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I'm developing a Google Maps web app and I'm using Google Maps autocomplete feature to pick places and save the address in the database. Right now I'm getting the full formatted address by using this https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=42.072845,19.516300

As you can see, the city name there is "Shkodër" but can also be searched as "Shkoder".

So in the database I may be saving either "Rruga Besnik Sykja, Shkodër, Albania" or "Rruga Besnik Sykja, Shkoder, Albania".

1)
 [image]

2) [image]

I am also using the Google Maps Autocomplete form to search for locations and I want to be able to select city from the autocomplete field and then display all locations I have saved in the database containing that city name.

My problem lies here: What if in the database I have received and saved the city name as "Shkodër" but in the search form users pick "Shkoder"? They wouldn't match and the user may not get the correct result from my database.

Is there any solid way to search all markers from a city even when the city name may change, using some general city ID or something?

I haven't been able to find anything useful so far...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Place ID`: https://developers.google.com/places/place-id

> A place ID is a textual identifier that uniquely identifies a place.
>   It looks like this:
>
> ChIJrTLr-GyuEmsRBfy61i59si0
>
> Place IDs are available for most locations, including businesses,
>   landmarks, parks, and intersections. These IDs are stable, meaning
>   that once you've identified the place ID for a place, you can reuse
>   that value when you next look up that place.
>
> You can use the same place ID across the Places API and a number of
>   Google Maps APIs. For example, you can use the same place ID to
>   reference a place in the Google Places API, the Google Maps JavaScript
>   API, the Google Maps Geocoding API, the Google Maps Embed API and the
>   Google Maps Roads API

Comment: Another advantage is the place_id is not subject to the restrictions on storing it persistently.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan - I just realized I hadn't marked this answer. I ended up "inventing" and implementing a different solution, but this seems interesting too. I may give it a try. Thanks for your time & help.

Comment: Place API seems deprecated now. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You can use componentRestrictions of google map api v3 for autocomplete

Here is the reference link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete